# matching column and lines on each word from file

Tags: c

I can't count the lines correctly!

My file is is for example `a1.txt`:

```
Words are flowing out \n
like \n
They \n
Pools dsa\n
Possessing
```

My code:

```
int main()
 {  
 FILE * file2; 
 file2 = fopen("a1.txt","r");
 int                c  ;        
 unsigned long       newline_count =1,sthlh_count=0;
 char str[56];
 while (fscanf(file2,"%s",str)!=EOF)    
    {
           c=fgetc(file2);
       printf("%s\n",str); 
           if ( c == '\n' ) newline_count++;
            if ( c == ' ' ) sthlh_count++;
            printf("%d %d\n",newline_count,sthlh_count);

    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using `fscanf` AND `fgetc`? Have you tried `while ( (c=fgetc(file2)) != EOF )` and dropping the existing fgetc line?

Comment: because i need edit the word ...i will try that moment but again the programm lose "some" lines !!!why ??

Comment: [   while ( (c=fgetc(file2)) != EOF )
    { 
        fscanf(file2,"%s",str);  ...... ] but again :(

Comment: The end of the line is in the spaces and newline(`" \n"`).

Comment: i agree but the dev-c return [Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] and wrong results again

Comment: use `fgets` and `strtok`.

Comment: Your printing for the counts will need to go outside the loop in the long run.  Note that `%s` will skip leading white space, so if you have blank lines in the input, they will not get counted reliably because some of the time the `%s` will read them instead of the `fgetc()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your problem is exactly, but I see one thing immediately.

```
 while (fscanf(file2,"%s",str)!=EOF)
```

In the body of the while loop, you  never use the value of `str` save for a `printf`. Remember, `fscanf` not only reads the file but moves a pointer in the file object that tells the runtime where you are in the file forward, so all of the characters that get read into str never get processed by the code in the body of the loop. This is why you're "losing lines."

Here's what you should be doing:

```
while ( (c=fgetc(file2)) != EOF ) ...
```

Here, you're just reading each character, storing it in `c`, then checking if it is `EOF`. Also, if you still want the printf to work, just print out this character in the body of the loop instead of printing the line. Drop the other fgetc line (or you're going to be "losing" characters!).

Comment: i understanded the problem which create the first code !!!you are right.. the c is int or char??

Comment: It should be a char, as `fgetc()` returns a char

Comment: i will need to save every word in a table , the best way is control if c='\n' and then stop table??

Comment: If you want to save every word in a table, allocate a buffer and save it and clear it whenever c == ' ', else add to it (don't forget size checks)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *file2 = fopen("a1.txt", "r");
    unsigned long newline_count = 0, word_count=0;
    char line[1024], *word , *delimiter = " \n";

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file2)){
        ++newline_count;
        for(word = strtok(line, delimiter); word ; word = strtok(NULL, delimiter)){
            printf("%lu %lu : %s\n", newline_count, ++word_count, word);
        }
    }
    fclose(file2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GP95 `file2` is pointer. Do you What is a `table` that you say?

Comment: @GP95 it like this `char table[16][56];`

Comment: i want  it like this char word[21]; because i have already my code and i use "table" and believe me it require many chances...

Comment: @GP95 The definition of the `table` that use of you?

Comment: you can see my first code up , i  use  " char str[56];" because i need that kind !!!and NOT pointer

Comment: @GP95 you use `" char str[56];"` as `table`. It requires a separate index for use as a table to the difficult to use it. Besides, it is very small.